# If one nuget package is dependepnt on another, should it reference the project or the nuget package?

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm publishing two nuget packages for use in other internal projects. One project is mostly just entities (the child project) and the other is business and other logic (the parent project). Our company prefers separating dependencies this way. The two projects are in the same solution.

My question is should the parent project directly reference the child project? Or should I first publish the child project, pull it into the parent project, and then publish the parent. That way it has a reference to the nuget package, not the child project itself.

Comment: Would anyone ever use the child by itself directly?  Would you ever supply updates to the child without necessarily updating the parent?

Comment: Yes to the first question for sure. The entities would be used all over the place (presentation layers, potentially repository layers, as well as business layers) and the logic layer would be used only within other business logic layers of other projects. I believe we would generally push updates to the projects at the same time. The point of separating them for us is to prevent people from using business logic in places they shouldn't, like repository layers.